# What's the meaning of this quote

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

One had as good be out of the world, as out of fashion.

It's by someone named Colley Ciber. Lived a long time ago so his quotes are a bit hard for me to understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's archaic, and would not be used in modern speech.  Tim's answer is correct as to the meaning.

Comment: Interpretation requests (in fact, all criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature) are out of scope and may be removed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  If there is a specific word you can't find a meaning for, or something specific you don't understand about the grammar, please [edit the question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/413828/edit).

Answer (score 3):

"Had as good" here means *might as well*. "Out of the world" implies *dead*, though it's not a direct meaning.

Comment: Which more correctly explains the quote? "One might as well be dead rather than out of fashion."  **or** "If one is out of fashion, they might as well be dead."  Basically are they saying it's better to be dead than out of fashion, or that being out of fashion is the same as being dead?